# Pop up openlayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am working on a map with different layers.
My goal would be to display the information of the layers with a pop up as explained in the [tutorial](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) of openlayer.
However testing the code I get as output:

> Uncaught TypeError: map.on is not a function

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you do the `var map = new ol.Map({ ... })` part? This is the part which will give you a map which is a jQuery object. Then, on that map object you can call `.on()`;

Answer (score 0):

`map.on` is not a function means that you have a map variable and it either does not have an `on` member, or, if it has, `on` is not a `function`. Since the error is not telling you that you cannot use `.on` of `undefined`, we have to assume that `map` is either incorrectly initialized or its initialization was not completed yet when you tried to call its `on`. This answer cannot give you any further information unless you specify your problem further.